# mongoengine: count the number of documents in a collection without retrieving all the documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

Suppose I have a class named Posts and it corresponds to a mongodb collection. If I do Posts.objects.count(). Sure it will give me the number of documents, but it first constructs the QuerySet and then counts the number of items inside. My collection has tens of millions of documents and doing this can incur a high overhead. Is there a way to count the number of documents without actually retrieving them from mongodb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this out by looking at the source code. Although this way is sketchy, it works. Every Document subclass has a method called _get_collection() which gives you a connection to the collection that corresponds to the subclass. Then use pymongo calls on this connection.